# what's the optimal way to store large amount of binary numbers in small memory (less than 50 MB)

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

For example, I have 1,000,000 (or several magnitudes more) binary numbers I need to store. I have less than 50 MB. How do array of boolean types occupy spaces?

I first tried to implement using array of integers, but it takes a lot of memory, which is unacceptable in e.g. an embedded device.

Can I also use an integer in binary form to represent 8 binary digits, which can reduce down the number of integers (by only a factor of 8 though)?

Comment: You need to know a lot more about your numbers than you are telling us.  What is their range ?  What is their distribution ?  Do any patterns exist ?  Is a lossy compression acceptable ?  If so, how much loss ?

Comment: If you mean you need to store a million bits, i.e., each 1 or 0, then by definition you can store 8 per byte, and typically 32 per integer, so a million bits is only 125k. If they are sparse (that is, mostly zeros with only accasional ones) you might look into Bloom filters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your numbers are limited by MAX, you can store 8 boolean in every byte, using Ceil(MAX/8) bytes

```
Set Nth bit in array:
ByteArr[N div 8] = ByteArr[N div 8] OR (1 << (N mod 8))
Clear Nth bit in array:
ByteArr[N div 8] = ByteArr[N div 8] AND !(1 << (N mod 8))
Get Nth bit:
BoolResult = 0 <> (ByteArr[N div 8] AND (1 << (N mod 8)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using a [compressed bitwise trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)